# How to get values based on 2 user inputs in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

As per below data, using Python how can I get **Headers** column value for the corresponding given  input from **DB & Table** column.

```
DB      Table   Headers
Oracle  Cust    Id,Name,Mail,Phone,City,County
Oracle  Cli     Cid,shopNo,State
Oracle  Addr    Street,Area,City,Country
SqlSer  Usr     Name,Id,Addr
SqlSer  Log     LogId,Env,Stg
MySql   Loc     Flat,Add,Pin,Country
MySql   Data    Id,Txt,TaskId,No
```

Output: Suppose if i pass, Oracle & Cli as parameters, then it should return the value as "Cid,shopNo,State" in a list.
Trying with python dictionary, but it takes 2 values key and value. But i have 3 values. how to get ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your data is in some sort of tabular format. In that case I would recommend using the `pandas` package, which is very convenient if you are working with tabular data.

`pandas` can read data into a DataFrame from a CSV file using `pandas.read_csv`. This dataframe you can then filter using the column names and the required values.

In the example below I assume that your data is tab (\t) separated. I read in the data from a string using `io.StringIO`. Normally you would just use `pandas.read_csv('filename.csv')`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """DB\tTable\tHeaders
Oracle\tCust\tId,Name,Mail,Phone,City,County
Oracle\tCli\tCid,shopNo,State
Oracle\tAddr\tStreet,Area,City,Country
SqlSer\tUsr\tName,Id,Addr
SqlSer\tLog\tLogId,Env,Stg
MySql\tLoc\tFlat,Add,Pin,Country
MySql\tData\tId,Txt,TaskId,No"""

dataframe = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\t')

db_is_oracle = dataframe['DB'] == 'Oracle'
table_is_cli = dataframe['Table'] == 'Cli'
filtered_dataframe = dataframe[db_is_oracle & table_is_cli]
print(filtered_dataframe)
```

This will result in :

```
       DB Table           Headers
1  Oracle   Cli  Cid,shopNo,State
```

Or to get the actual headers of the first match:

```py
print(filtered_dataframe['Headers'].iloc[0])
>>> Cid,shopNo,State
```